# Probability of at most two events happening.

Tags: probability

> We are given that $A_1 A_2 A_3 ..... A_n$ are events of a field $f$. At least one of these events is certain to occur, but certainly, no more than two occur.

I have trouble expressing this in the form of equations.
The first condition (at least one occur) can be expressed as 
$$1-P(A_1^c\,\cap A_2^c\,\cap A^c_3 ......A^c_n)=1$$
$$\implies P(A_1\,\cup A_2\,\cup A_3 ......A_n)=1$$

For the second condition (at most two occur). I'm thinking on the lines of, 
$$P(\text {at most two occur} )=P(\text {No event occurs}) + P(\text {Exactly one event occurs}) + P(\text {Exactly two event occur})$$
But I'm not able to translate that into mathematical terms.
I found the following answer somewhere online, 
$$\Sigma P(A_i) - \Sigma P(A_i\cap A_j) = 1$$ 
Please explain this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from the condition that "at least one of the event is certain to occur", you already obtained the formula

$$ P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1 $$

In the LHS of the above equation, it is a probability of union of events, in which you can apply inclusion-exclusion principle on it to break it into an alternative series:

$$ \begin{align} 
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) &= \sum P(A_i) - \sum P(A_i \cap A_j)
+ \sum P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) \\
& - \ldots - (-1)^n\sum P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)
\end{align}$$

The terms with probability of intersection of 3 or more events vanish because you apply the condition that "no more than two events occur". As a result, only the first two terms remains and hence we have the answer above.

Comment: could you elaborate a little? +1 for the answer!